# jqGrid - How To Post A Default ("Static") Field Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, jqgrid

My `colModel`, among other fields, includes the following:

```
...
{
    name: 'object', 
    editable: false, 
    editoptions: {defaultValue: 'owner'}, 
    hidden: false
},
...
```

This field is not a part of my database and I don't want it visible in the grid or add/edit/delete forms; I simply want to always submit the field `object` with the value `owner` regardless of add/update/delete when using form editing.

I was able to get `object=owner` to `POST` when inserting a new record, as well as when deleting, but research leads me to believe that `editoptions` `defaultValue` is not what I need for updating.  Not sure what to do.

I use...

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) 
{
    jQuery("#ownerGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid);
},
```

...to open the edit form as well as the the grid's default edit button.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having come up empty handed looking for a "correct" easily-identifiable way I changed my `object` field to...

```
{
    name: 'object', 
    editable: true, 
    editoptions: {value: 'owner:owner', defaultValue: 'owner'}, 
    edittype: 'checkbox', 
    hidden: true
}
```

I am certain there may be a better way but this works.  Easy enough.

Thanks.